# Adding up Facebook Like counts from subdomains

Tags: facebook, count, facebook-like

I have a main English website and a Spanish website: **website.info** and **website.info/es**

The websites are built in Wordpress using Multisite multilingual. The English version and Spanish version now each have different Facebook LIKE counts. Is there a way of adding the counts from both "websites" and show the total count on both?

Comment: Have you tried anything or done any research?

Comment: @Caribou what do you think?! This is for help not for ironic rhetoric questions.

Comment: It isn't an answer, I was indicating that you should put more detail. Your question is light on content. More detail would get you more responses -SO questions should be useful to others having similar issues - so it wasn't rhetorical but I make a small apology for not being more direct

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize there was not enough detail :(

Comment: hey np - you got an answer :) +1 because I for got to earlier ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Graph uses URLs as the unique identifier to aggregate likes against. In Facebook's backend, all the likes are associated to whatever URL you define in your `og:url` meta tag.

Judging by your question, you seem to use different URLs for the Spanish language version of your site, so there's no way to merge those likes. You could settle on one of the versions being the "authoritative" version, but the problem you'll have then is that when a user shares that URL, FB will always drive traffic to the definitive version you've set.

In essence - if a Spanish user shared from the Spanish page, FB would always drive the traffic to the English version, if that's what you set in your `og:url`. If you're ok with that, then once you make the change, the likes will aggregate there. Any likes you've gotten up to now on the 'other' page will be lost though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Colm. If there isn't another solution I will use this. My intention was to redirect traffic to the proper version of the website, so the Spanish likes would go to the Spanish version of the website.

Comment: I agree it's  not ideal. You could also use something [like this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/internationalization/). Either way, if the answer was useful, don't forget to upvote/accept it, so it's easier for others to find in the future.